# Overloading interface methods in Java

Tags: java, interface, overloading

I have the following code:

```
public interface Block {
    public double[] getOutput();
    public double[] getOutput(double[] inputs);
}

public class Dataset implements Block{

    public double[] getOutput(){
        return(new double[0]);
    }
}
```

I'm using netbeans IDE, and It produces the following message:

```
Dataset is not abstract and does not override abstract method getOutput(double[]) in Block
```

I'm unsure as to why this is happening .. any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can't you understand what it is telling you?

Comment: Where is the implementation of this `public double[] getOutput(double[] inputs);` method in your class (by convention)?

Comment: I have misunderstood how function overloading works, I believe. I assumed that I would only need to provide an implementation for one of the two function within Block depending on whether I pass any parameters or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Dataset` class must provide an implementation for the `getOutput(double[])` function. As written, it only provides an implementation for `getOutput()` (with no arguments).

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding function overloading - I assumed that I would only need to provide an implementation for one of the two functions as they are overloaded ?

Comment: Java considers functions with different arguments (even if they have the same name) to be different functions that are treated separately. You must override both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface demands two methods and you provided one. QED.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it pretty good. You need to implement all methods of an interface when you implement it.